# Switch an image within an anchor to text when the anchor is hovered over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to have a logo (say .item-logo) being displayed in the circle when it is not being hovered upon, as hovering into the container will display the date.

**HTML**

```
<div id="main-content" class="container animated"> <div id="content">
 <article class="post-65 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-thoughts tag-example tag-standard tag-tag item-list">
 <div class="post-format-icon">
 <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" class="item-date"><span><?php the_time('j') ?></span><small><?php the_time('M') ?></small></a>
</div>
```

You may take a look at the JS Fiddle here, the date is not seen as it's php. With that being said, the logo should change to the date when being hovered. http://jsfiddle.net/xJv5x/

Thanks!

Comment: the fiddle is missing

Comment: @AdonisK.I have added it in the link.

Comment: what i understand is you need an image to show in circle and when you hover on that circle, image will be hidden and date will appear. Am I on right track?

Comment: You should replace the php scripts with the served HTML

Comment: @Era yes you are. in you want to see it in action, here's the site: http://bit.ly/JLotEI. Currently, there's no image.

Comment: I think Matthew already worked upon that. check his link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is really easy to achieve with CSS. Bascially you hide the image inside the anchor and show something else when you hover, e.g.

```
<a href="#foo">
    <div>02-01</div>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/100" />
</a>

a div, a:hover img {display:none;}
a:hover div {display:block;}
```

and here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gwDWS/

Comment: Thank you very much, here's to a Happy New Year!